# Displaying parent/child data in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to create a document that displays a list of items, with details below each item.  I feel like what I'm trying to do should be relatively simple, and the answer is hiding under my nose, but I can't find what I'm looking for.

For an example, let's say I'm just listing people, with a child list of their favorite foods.

This is how the data will eventually be displayed:

```
DOE,      JOHN       AGE:31
      Apple
      Pie
      Cookies

SMITH,    JANE       AGE:95
      Oats
      Bananas
      Prunes
```

I'm returning a single table from the database structured as such:

```
USERID  LASTNAME  FIRSTNAME  AGE  FAVORITEFOOD
100     DOE       JOHN       31   Apple
100     DOE       JOHN       31   Pie
100     DOE       JOHN       31   Cookies
101     SMITH     JANE       95   Oats
101     SMITH     JANE       95   Bananas
101     SMITH     JANE       95   Prunes
```

I'm trying to do this with a gridview control.  I'm not sure that's what I should be using.  But what I'm having trouble with, is getting the gridview to only list items with a unique USERID.  And then using that unique USERID to list each item individually below.

Is there any kind of "automated" way of pulling this off using standard .net controls without going in and manually piecing it all together from the codebehind?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like a modelling problem rather than a control problem.  FAVORITEFOOD should be a sub-table with USERID as a foreign key.

Comment: I agree with @DanDaviesBrackett.  The table contains a lot of redundant data which could cause issues down the road like update anomalies.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling that might be a problem.  The thing that was getting me about doing it your way, is that I'm using SqlDataSource, which only allows one recordset at a time.  So I would need to create one stored procedure to return the first portion (user info), and another stored procedure to return detail information for each user (favorite foods).  If I'm dealing with thousands of users, that's a lot of db queries.  I thought it might be more efficient, performance-wise, to just pull it all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you get a unique query, assuming userid, lastname, firstname, and age are duplicate, (e.g. Select distinct USERID,  LASTNAME,  FIRSTNAME,  AGE from table) into a DataTable and get another query (e.g. Select USERID, FAVORITEFOOD from table) into another DataTable that are both in the same DataSet, you could setup a [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx). [GetChildRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135362.aspx) can then be used to show the child information, based on the selected parent information. I don't have experience with showing it the way you are asking, but it has worked for two grids, one whose ItemSource is the parent and the other is the GetchildRows method (based on the selected row in the parent). Not sure if that helps or not...